# proper iBatis method for SELECT ~~~ FOR UPDATE oracle SQL query?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, transactions, ibatis

I'm developing a web-based service using jBoss5 + Struts + iBatis.

Is there any proper method for "SELECT ... FOR UPDATE" oracle query (I mean, select iBatis method which involves transaction management)??

....

My question is this. A certain part of my program causes RX lock of some rows of a table.

source like below,

```
try{
    sqlMap.startTransaction();
    ...
    HashMap someMap = (HashMap)sqlMap.queryForObject("theSelectSQLusesForUpdate",someOtherMap);
    // usually hangs at the sentence above
    ...
    //inserts, updates, selects, ~~~
    ...
    sqlMap.commitTransaction();
} catch block {} finally {
    sqlMap.endTransaction();
}
```

I found that "SELECT ... FOR UPDATE" sentences are treated as DML by Oracle.
So, my SQL which uses "FOR UPDATE" should involve some kind of transaction management, but iBatis doesn't support for it as the query is defined in  ...  block.

Again my question, Is there any proper method for "SELECT ... FOR UPDATE" oracle query (I mean, select iBatis method which involves transaction management)??

if someone gives me the answer, he or she is my savior..

thanks.